# How to redirect on a particular tab panel in tab container in page load?

Tags: asp.net, tabs, tabpanel

I am using Ajax Tabcontainer and Tab panels. There are 4 tabs. Different users can use this application. Based on some condition, I want users to redirect to specific Tabs on page load.

How can we do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ActiveTabIndex` to select the tab you want in the `page_load` event.

**[More Info](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Tabs/Tabs.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `TabControl.ActiveTabIndex` with your Tab Index number. that will directly redirect on that tab page according to your condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
If (Username == "Admin")
    TabContainer.ActiveTabIndex = 0;
else
    TabContainer.ActiveTabIndex = 1;
```